# Change groups on new page

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to create a summary page in crystal reports where it groups all the details with the same ItemName and calculates the totals

```
Data Example:
Balls        50
Balls        75
Food         10
Dolls        45
Food         68
```

On the last page in the report I need it to say

```
Balls          125
Food           78
Dolls          45
```

The report is already grouped by another detail, is there anyway to change what the report is grouped by on the last page?

Comment: One option  is you can use report in report footer. To try for better solution explai  more about different groups used in report

Comment: @Siva You mean to say `Sub Report` in report footer

Comment: Yes correct......try rhat

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without a subreport?

Answer (score 0):

Insert a cross-tab object in the report footer. Use the text field in your example as the 'row' field in the cross-tab.  Use the numeric field in your example as the 'summarized' field. Leave the 'column' field blank.